# Filter all find queries on entity CakePHP 3.6

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7, cakephp-3.6

let's say that I have an articles database and I want to only display articles that are published on the site (where published = 1). Instead of adding the condition in every find queries like the following:

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find('all')->where(['published' => 1]);
```

Is there a way that I can automatically apply this condition on all the find queries in the whole application at one place? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `beforeFind`. This will be fired before every find query on your Article Model. Here is the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind)

Here is how to use it

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary)
{

    $query->where(['article.visible' => 1]);

    return $query;
}
```